# Firestore 9 onSnapshot TypeScripot error: Spread types may only be created from object types. ts(2698)

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When calling the `data()` method inside a Firestore 9 `onSnapshot` function it returns an Object containing all fields in the document.

But in my code below there is a TypeScript error on `...doc.data()` that says: `Spread types may only be created from object types. ts(2698)`

So if `data()` returns an object, why is TypeScript complaining that it is not an object?

```
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
    collectionOrdered,
    (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        documents.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
      });
      error.value = null;
      console.log(documents);
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(err.message);
      documents.splice(0);
      error.value = err.message;
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had trouble finding it, but it looks like the `doc` inside `snapshot` needed to by typed as `doc: DocumentData`.

Full code example:

```
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
    collectionOrdered,
    (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc: DocumentData) => {
        documents.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
      });
      error.value = null;
      console.log(documents);
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(err.message);
      documents.splice(0); //Clears reactive array
      error.value = err.message;
    }
  );
```